# Vertical submenu layout and behavior incorrect

Tags: css, submenu, onhover

Vertical submenu postion is correct but links are on top of each other. And it won't hide when hovering in main menu. Hides when hovering outside menu. I don't know what to add/change in css.

[Vertical submenu](http://www.villalotus.net/TEST/test.html)

```
nav {
    padding-top: 183px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
    ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul a {
    display: block;
    width: 145px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #004c99;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 9px;
}
nav ul a:active       {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li a:hover, ul a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #6699cc;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul a:link, nav ul a:visited {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -35px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 165px;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #6699cc;
}
nav ul ul li a:active, ul ul li a:link , ul ul li a:visited{
    background-color: #3370AD;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you include a screenshot or a link? just saw the link sorry

Answer (score 0):

change your nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;} to      ... margin-top:5px and see if that does the job. that will fix the spacing issue anyway

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately it didn't help. It only added space in parent menu.

Comment: nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    /*text-align:left;*/
    color: #fff;
    width: 230px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 165px;
    
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #6699cc;
}
nav ul li ul li a:active, ul li ul li a:link , ul li ul li a:visited{
    background-color: #3370AD;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
i changed the above and it improved.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I nested the submenu incorrectly:

```
<ul id="main menu">

    <li> 
        <a>Menu item</a> 
        <!-- DO NOT CLOSE THIS LI TAG YET! -->

        <ul>
            <li>Submenu item</li>
        </ul>

    </li> <!-- NOW YOU CAN CLOSE IT -->

</ul>
```